# Typescript type to prevent division by 0

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, divide-by-zero

I am creating a calculation system for training purpose with typescript and I get a typing error during division.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

```js
type Variable = {
    value: number
    resolve: () => number
}

type NoZeroVariable = {
    value: Omit<number, 0>
    resolve: () => Omit<number, 0>
}

// then when I try to resolve the operation
a.resolve() / b.resolve()
```

I get this error :
`The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.(2363)`

Comment: I think you've left out your arithmetic code. `a` and `b` are `undefined` in [your example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwEYBtoF4oG8CwAUFCVAG5zoCuEAXFAHZUC2qECRpUCEAzgPboydKAAoAlFCwA+RizYdCAXyJFQkKADl+ALXb94yNJil5OpCtREB5ZkmAAeJq3YAaKAAZp5kjwFCRCSlZW3sneTdPb2VVQgB6OKhgAAsIBigAd1T0gEkkhBAk-m4+QWEk1Kh+SAQ4YCR+BiI4ADo-MoggxNQ20oCJIA), and there is no code performing any arithmetic.

Comment: `Omit<number, 0>` won't exclude `0` from all possible numbers.. Have a look at `Omit` docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Comment: I think you want to use `Exclude` instead of `Omit`

Comment: There are no negated types in TypeScript; you can filter unions, but `number` is not a union.  There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding exactly to non-zero numbers.  You can write a generic constraint like captainyossarian did but that means everything touching it needs to be generic as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have very simple implementation:

```js
type NonZero<T extends number> = T extends 0 ? never : number extends T ? never : T


const division = <
    A extends number,
    B extends number
>(a: A, b: NonZero<B>) =>
    a / b

division(10, 2) // ok
division(10, 0) // error


const higherOrderFunction = (b: number) => division(10, b) // error, b is not verified


`NonZero` - expects a number. If number is has a literal representation like `1`,`2` or any other literal it returns this number, otherwise (if it is `0` or `number`) it returns `never`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwFoQE5wDwBUoQB7AQIAmAzlAgK4C2ARmgHxQC8UO%20hJ5ADFAPwUIANzRQAXBRr1UuAkTJt%20gkTIlYAUJoDGiUsCjEAlkMOlDiFlAzqotqAEFZnBVTpoANDbsAhJ-PKu0uoMABQAhhL27lC0EvDIaJjeDACULAxetmFQAPQxmkYmZoghAIzc0QBMaTl5cADW6oWm5ghlFVDcNXlo6Kia6joIelAAFoYA5qNoAPKoxGgAYpQIWsCtliGxkm6oacxMzcVt5dG03biofWdQphRw%20iqGAGaGEMTqQA)

`b` expected to be only literal number. It can't event be some variable with type of `number` because you don't know the value in runtime.

Let's proceed wot your example:

```js
type Variable<N extends number> = {
  value: N
  resolve: () => number
}


type NonZero<T extends number> = T extends 0 ? never : number extends T ? never : T


const variableDivision = <
  Num1 extends number,
  Num2 extends number,

  >(a: Variable<Num1>, b: Variable<NonZero<Num2>>) =>
  a.resolve() / b.resolve()

variableDivision({ value: 42, resolve: () => 42 }, { value: 42, resolve: () => 0 }) // ok
variableDivision({ value: 42, resolve: () => 42 }, { value: 0, resolve: () => 0 }) // expected error
```

It is impossible in TypeScript to overload division operator `/` like in `F#`.

Hence, you need to create an extra function for division.

`Num2` is infered number from `b` variable. If it is `0`, `NonZero` returns `never` and the whole `b` argument becomes `Variable<never>`. SInce `never` is unrepresentable, you are getting error.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwEYBsIB4ByUIAewEAdgCYDOUJArgLaoQIB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFABucdDQgAuKDj4CEECgHt0giVAAUASnataDJnwC%20fY71CQpCkgC0mCrABV8RUpWr1GLdlEeFi5KgAMUAD81BAqCFCSuh5Ofq6OoSThTFHeJnwAxpYUwEKIKBgQACJIgkgUSJZeWDJS9ACMcS5UMUwANHU49ABMzf5uegidvHXManCS8MhomLiNzO1QqFMFs9g4ljYIdt10PczMWmzMdXAAdHKKyhCaUAD0y5fySiqaJsIzRaXllZZqnHyolUABYeksrq9VHcTlAwVADEtAcJgZIwRCXjdJDDWEEDFp7o8FABrPifQqYH4VKokAFAsRo8FQSFY9THVjwxFcemqAIY64qbHsqB4gmPQiQTLEMj4BA7BAZXhAA)