# Checking type of a type argument

Tags: typescript

I'm creating an arithmetic program for training purposes on typescript.

I have a problem with a dynamic type (note that T is either `number` or `noZero`.) :

```js
type noZero = Exclude<number, 0>

class Pow<T extends number> extends Calcul<T> {
    public a: Calcul<number>

    resolve(variable?: Variable<T>): Calcul<T> | T {
        if (this.n.resolve() === 1) {
            if (this.a.resolve() === 0 && ???) {
                return this.a as Calcul<0>
            }
            return this.a as Calcul<T>
        }
    }
}
```

I use this system to prevent division by 0.
The resolve function can return a `Calcul` in case of the presence of a variable (like `4√(x)`).

So I'd like to know if it's possible to check the value of `T` to raise an error. If not, is there a solution to my problem ?

[Here some more code for context.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=16&pln=41&pc=63#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-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-b3wACTcaB3WgABrCNPT9YgNHOqB3QQUh8ua11kPwA7DoPAAhcgNA-DpvjCDQrsIqBfXBkCbBe-snKPVAKQ0EDyKfF8FxAlQeGgYk3E7AMCY4L6CHfAA5flr19O7KegPGAVoSGjExZsUmfKmwEgV1kCYLL+2-VAyASYhOHPMCIPpftXT9aBmFsNw7rg10cppzRrkapqICdFriuIcLplUndGs1EENa1qWFr1vLShE43TeCqAAFk7t9AM0PdIFZp1xLzXKiyIG1djyN5etw295KKokAOHAfegRKjw8DI+XNugV33vXM71Sis1TyNuES-UbVq2w7AFUh7PsByHEdIPHSdsxkIA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript type to prevent division by 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612540/typescript-type-to-prevent-division-by-0)

Comment: This `Exclude<number, 0>` does not work in a way you expect because `number` is not a union